# pl/sql не удаётся запустить процедуру из анонимного блока

Tags: oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте.

У меня дана процедура:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE find_area_pop(
    p_country_id wf_countries.country_id%TYPE := 0, 
    p_country_name OUT wf_countries.country_name%TYPE,
    p_country_population OUT wf_countries.country_population%TYPE,
    p_country_square OUT wf_countries.country_square%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN

   SELECT country_name, country_population, country_square
   INTO p_country_name, p_country_population, p_country_square
   FROM wf_countries
   WHERE country_id = p_country_id;

   EXCEPTION 
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Population of country at id = ' || 
      p_country_id || ' not found');
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Query returns population more than one country'                    || CHR(10) || 'or another error is occured!!!');
END;
```

После того как процедура была создана, я сразу запускаю такой анонимный блок:

```
DECLARE
    v_country_name VARCHAR2(60);
    v_population NUMBER := 0;
    v_country_square NUMBER := 0;
    density NUMBER := 0;
    v_id wf_countries.country_id%TYPE;

BEGIN
    find_area_pop( 
         v_population, 
         v_country_square,
         p_country_id => v_id,
         p_country_name => v_country_name
     );

 IF(v_country_name IS NOT NULL) THEN
      BEGIN
           density := v_population/v_country_square;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country: ' || v_country_name 
           ||', population: ' || v_population || ', total country density: '         
           || density);
      END;
 END IF;

 EXCEPTION 
      WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Square of the country cannot be equal 0!!!');

 END;

Но в результате компиляции у меня появляется ошибка:

ORA-06550: line 9, column 6:
PLS-00703: multiple instances of named argument in list
ORA-06550: line 9, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Вы явно скажете , что у меня ошибка в вызове процедуры find_area_pop при подобный расстановке параметров и скажете мне , что я бы мог так не делать. Но это не возможно. Мне нужно согласно заданию , чтобы этот код стал работать и при этом , чтобы при вызове процедуры расстановка параметров была такая: первые два параметра с позиционной нотацией(конечные значения) , а последние две с именованной нотацией(ссылки на конечные значения). Как мне исправить код , чтобы он заработал. Жду решений.

С уважением.
Дима.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку первые два параметра у Вас позиционные, то компилятор считает, что это p_country_id и p_country_name (так объявлена функция). А затем Вы передаёте их же ещё раз по имени, отсюда и ошибка. Правильным решением будет так:

```
find_area_pop( 
     v_coutry_id,
     v_country_name, 
     p_population => ..., 
     p_country_square => ...,
     );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Надо будет это записать ))

Comment: Поставьте тогда, что это верный ответ. :-)